# How to make soundwave in react native that can drag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to archive something like this

[image]

I found some lib to make Soundwave on react-native, but problem how can i drag this? Like it keep static line, and make the wave moving, how can do that animation?

Please help, i only need the way